# Knockout JS -Radio click event not updating the DOM

Tags: knockout.js

DOM:

```
self.setVisible=function(question,event){
    alert(event.target.value);
    question.answer(event.target.value)
    alert(event.target.value);
}
```

The click event inside array of knockout js radio button is not updating the DOM
Explanation of Problem:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind='click: setVisible' value="Yes"  /> Yes 
<input type="radio" data-bind='click: setVisible' value="No"/> No
```

There are two radio button Yes and No,generated dynamically in an array.If I add a click event the selected checkbox is not updating.

Now,When I click yes first it is checked but from the next time if i click "No" again Yes is only getting checked.I am wondering whats wrong.

Note:If I remove the click event its working perfectly.Please find the DOM in the comment I have added.

Comment: The DOM is as below:<input type="radio" data-bind='disable: $parent.momentDisabledStatus,attr: { name: "yesNoAnswerGroup["+$index()+"]"},checked: answer' value="Yes"  /> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input type="radio" data-bind='disable: $parent.momentDisabledStatus,attr: { name: "yesNoAnswerGroup["+$index()+"]"},checked: answer' value="No"/> No

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use edits to make the question complete. Note there's a toolbar and markdown help as well, to help you format code so the question becomes more readable.

Comment: Hi I resolved the issue:

                self.setChildVisible=function(question,event){
         event.target.checked=event.target.value;
         return event.target.checked;
        }

We have to return the checked value.So the DOM will get updated with the latest value

Comment: Hey @user3128689, good to hear. Note that you can (and preferred that you do) answer your own question, so it's easier for others with the same problem to spot the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understood the question, but I think you need to add a name to the inputs to get the working as expected:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" data-bind='click: setVisible' value="Yes" /> Yes 
<input type="radio" name="test" data-bind='click: setVisible' value="No"/> No
```

I have [made a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7W9K4/).

Comment: Thanks Martyn,I have added name also but both are same.I inspected the DOM.But it is not enabling the clicked radio button.Even in you demo I cant see the checkbox enable after the alert